# How to use Auth0's CredentialsManager for Local Biometric Auth with React Native

Tags: react-native, auth0, keystore, password-less

The [auth0 documentation on their credentials manager](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0#credentials-manager) states

> The credentials manager is an easy to use source of Keychain-based
> authentication for iOS and Android, and should be usable with
> auth.credentialsManager

When trying to use this suggested method

```
const isLoggedIn = await auth0.credentialsManager.hasValidCredentials();
```

This error is being thrown

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[10], 
"../context/actions/authActions").auth0.credentialsManager.getCredentials')
```

Here's an overview of our auth0 configuration, and how it works currently

in AuthActions.js

```
export const auth0 = new Auth0({
  domain: Config.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  clientId: Config.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
});


export const actionLogin = async (callback) => {
  try {
      const authState = await auth0.webAuth.authorize({
           scope: 'openid profile email offline_access',
           audience: Config.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
           prompt: 'login',
      });

      let response = await getState(authState, callback);
      return response

  } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error Authenticating: ', e)
  }
```

The hasValidCredentials() method mentioned above is called after a user has successfully authenticated with the webAuth, and it should be returning something along the lines of an access token, refresh token, id, and email per the docs

Note that we are trying to use this so that we can stop using the react-native-keychain package and use auth0's implementation of the native keystores by

```
await auth0.credentialsManager.requireLocalAuthentication();
```

Answer (score 1):

We managed to solve this issue by doing the following:

1. Call `await auth0.credentialsManager.requireLocalAuthentication()` in a `useEffect` in the `App.tsx` file or where appropriate as long as it's before your login screen. I agree that the name is not straightforward but it's basically allowing the user to use biometrics.
2. Call the `hasValidCredentials()` function.
3. Create a `const credentials` where you conditionally check the value of step 1.

   If false, call the `webAuth` function. This will return a set of Credentials. If true, call `getCredentials()`
4. Save the credentials (this may be optional as stated in the docs in the following link: [Retrieve stored credentials](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0#retrieve-stored-credentials))
5. Every time you login now, it should always check if auth0 has any credentials stored. It even does the `accessToken` renewal with the `refreshToken` that you saved.

```
const credentials = !hasValidCredentials 
    ? await webAuth.authorize({...}).catch((error) => { ... })
    : auth0.manager.getCredentials()

const credentialsParams: SaveCredentialsParams = { ...credentials }
auth0.manager.saveCredentials(credentials)
```

Comment: where from and how to import auth0 ? I'm only able to import `import Auth0 from 'react-native-auth0'` and that does not contain the credentialsManager..

Comment: auth0 is a singleton component that we created that instantiates the Auth0 class. You can access the credentials manager from there.